# Android - Debugging referenced project problem

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I have 3 projects in Eclipse Helios.

1. A (java project)
2. B (Android library project)
3. C (Android application project)

The references are set like this:
B references A and C references B.

In my activity in project C i created an instace of a class thats in my project A.
I set a breakpoint on this line and in the class constructor in project A.

I hit debug and i get exception "Invocation target exception" - Class File Editor: Source not found.And the app crashes, breakpoint in project A never gets hit.

If i referece project A directly in project C both breakpoints get hit (only if i hit proceed after the first breakpoint). But if i step into project A i get the same error.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What Java version is/was used to build project A? I believe Android is based on Java 1.5, so if you're building project A with a newer Java compiler, that is possibly the cause.

Comment: Project A is  Java 1.6 but under "Preferences/Java Compiler/" i have set "Compiler compliance level" to 1.4, because the same project is also referenced in J2ME project (made with EclipseME). If i dont set to 1.4 my J2ME project is not working.

Comment: Can you post the logcat output?

Comment: When deployed/debugging, is it possible that the library is running as a different Android user ID? A quick rummage around Google shows the most relevant [result](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/276ea9cff2cf2b5d) appears to be permissions related. In either case, the logcat output may help narrow down the problem.

Comment: i get: NoDefClassFoundError (the class that im creating instance) in LogCat.

Comment: There are two things I would suggest at this point - 1. Ensure the projects B and C are in the CLASSPATH. 2. If possible, add the source of project B and C to project A - this will at least confirm that those projects can be made to work on Android.

Comment: 1. If checking "Properties/Java Build Path" in every project all seems fine. Project B has project A under "Projects" tab. Under "Order and Export" project A is listed and checked. In properties of project C its the same story. Project B is listed in "Projects" tab and also checked under "Order and Export". LogCat still gives me error in project C when creating instance of a class that lives in project A. But the compiler gives no error in project C (import and code creating instance appear good). It works however if i reference project A directly from project C...

Comment: 2. I cannot do that. Project A contains linked source (CORE) that i use in many other projects (J2ME, SE) that work with no error in same structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly the same structure  A - Java project (commonlibs), B Android Lib Project(ndkfoo2) and C Android App.

You have to make sure in the Properties for C you only reference the Library project in the Android section and not reference it in the Java build path too.  I made that mistake. Also no reference to A should be here either that is handled in B.

[image]

Then just reference A in B and you should be good to go.  Only issues you will have is debugging into your A project seems there is a bug in the eclipse that prevents you from setting your source to layered projects in Android.