# Jar referenced from android library project not referenced by App. NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, jar, adt, android-library

I have searched SO and tried all the solutions I came across but nothing seems to work. The things I tried are the solutions given [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308331/java-library-in-an-android-library-referenced-by-an-android-project-throws-nocla), [here](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940418/jars-added-to-an-android-library-are-not-getting-referenced-in-the-project) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565747/android-debugging-referenced-project-problem) but nothing seems to work.

As described in some of those question I have a java library (lets say J) included in a android library (AL) that is included in a android app (AA). I have added the library to the libs of both (have also tried with adding it to just AA and including in AL, and vice-versa and just in AL and expecting android dependencies to take care of it) but that or anything else did not work.

I am using the latest tools(version 20.0.3). 
The build android version for the android library and the app is 2.2 and min SDK is 5.

I can see the the java library in the android dependencies of the app but am getting a `NoClassDefFoundException` and run time.

How can I get this to work?

The android library must reference a jar, since that contains some encryption logic that I need to hide. The library is being created for distribution, the app is just something quite simple for testing the library.

Comment: Where are you putting the Android library (AL) in your Android app (AA)?  As in, where in the filesystem of your project is it located?

Comment: Also, are the NoClassDefFound errors only for your java library J?  Can use other functionality in AL that does not rely on J?

Comment: Yes. Only for functions/classes in the java library J. They are all different folders in the same root directory. All also share the same workspace. Found the solution though by trial and error. It working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 different but related problems causing this issue.

1. The Java library, J was compiled with compliance level 1.7 (default for my system). This needs to be at 1.5, the compliance level of Android. (compliance level may change in the future).
2. The J library was also compiling using the J2SE library. I had to replace that with the anroid.jar of the same api level as my app.

Then also things didn't work and for some reason it started working after I deleted the project and recreated in new directories.(IMP: take a code backup first).